# Calculating prices in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, currency

I have some energy readings that are fractional numbers like: `167512562.211221`.

I need to convert these numbers into an invoice price using a kWh price value.

But `Number` in JavaScript is floating point and unsuitable for monetary calculations.

How should I do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat this is a native javascript api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a library.

There are many and this page will help you along with the things you need to know about working with money in JavasScript.

https://frontstuff.io/how-to-handle-monetary-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

One solution you could try is storing your numbers as the smallest division of the currency you are working in (e.g if you're dealing in dollars, store you values as cents so $1.00 becomes `100` and $5.45 becomes `545`.

You will need to round your numbers after calculating from the fractional reading, using [round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), [ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) or [floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) depending on what is appropriate for your business logic, but after that, things like additions and subtractions can be carried out without worrying about the downsides of floating point.

If you need to apply further fractional logic (percentage discount etc) the values can simply be rounded using the appropriate function after the calculation is applied.